# Windows Form application C# stops responding in between timer tick events

Tags: c#, timer

I have a code in which I have started a timer tick event of 75 sec. The application is supposed to perform a task, at a time interval of 75 sec. The application just runs fine sometimes for 5 hrs, however all of a sudden it shows not responding...whenever other operations are done on the computer like opening other files...

My code looks like this:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    tmrTimer.Enabled = true;
}

private void tmrTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do my stuff here;
}
```

Comment: Any answer here would just be a guess. Your code given looks good. My guess would be just running out of system resources because of whatever that other code is doing, also hanging can often be the result of a while loop or similar. Have you ran a debug, what error is showing up ?

Comment: Your code looks just fine. I guess something happened in the Tick event handler. Can you show me what's in the event handler?

Comment: I don't think it anything to do with the code that you've posted. I think it's code you haven't posted. You might need to show us more.

Comment: @n099y - You were right, I found a bug in my logic. I  could correct it, and the code is working just fine.

Comment: @Sweeper - Thank you for the support

Comment: @Enigmativity - you were right....i got the same fixed

Answer (score 0):

I think it maybe because you used Timer from `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` class. This kind of Timers are Single Thread Timers; which means they use the same thread that your UI use. So, it's obvious why your application shows not responding when the thread has lots of things to do.
I suggest to change the timer type and try this one: `System.Threading.Timers`.

Comment: You don't have any limitation. For each timer, you're actually creating a new Thread. But remember, debugging in multi-thread is not as easy as debugging in single thread application.